How to observe progress of fileCompletedCount with Swift keypath?
I am trying to replace old fashioned Objective-C way of observation to modern swift way of observation. However I cannot figure out the keypath.
//doesn't work
progress.observe(\.userInfo[ProgressUserInfoKey.fileCompletedCountKey], changeHandler: {_,_ in
        
})

Foundation/NSObject.swift:132: Fatal error: Could not extract a String from KeyPath \NSProgress.userInfo.<computed 0x00000001a5a1ecf0 (Optional<Any>)>

PS: You cannot observe fileCompletedCount because is a computed property.
PS2: I don't think this is a duplicate question. See the image: it is being made manually a dynamic property.
Old code:
import Cocoa
private var viewControllerObservationContext = 0

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    private var progress: Progress = {
        let progress = Progress()
        progress.kind = .file
        progress.fileTotalCount = 20
        return progress
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let filesCompletedKeyPath = "userInfo.NSProgressFileCompletedCountKey"
        progress.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: filesCompletedKeyPath, options: .new, context: &viewControllerObservationContext)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            self.progress.fileCompletedCount = 10
        }
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        guard context == &viewControllerObservationContext else {
            super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
            return
        }
        print(object)
        print(keyPath)
    }

    deinit {
        progress.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "userInfo.NSProgressFileCompletedCountKey")
    }
}



You've hit upon a big difference between Objective-C KVC keypaths and Swift keypaths; Swift has none of the "magic" that lets you make a path into a dictionary. You will either have to observe the whole userInfo dictionary or else observe some property that is explicitly observable, such as the fractionCompleted or whatever. Or else just keep on keeping on with the way you're doing it now.

Does this answer your question? Is key-value observation (KVO) available in Swift?

@Willeke No. Is not marked as dynamic but still it sends KVO notifications. Dynamic keyword just adds what I have highlighted on image.  https://imgur.com/a/ONq4vCp

A key-value pair in a NSDictionary is not a dynamic property. It is not possible to create a KeyPath that is convertible to String. That's why you're using "NSProgressFileCompletedCountKey" instead of ProgressUserInfoKey.fileCompletedCountKey.

@Willeke I found another solution which is not linked to your suggested close answer.

Observe the localizedDescription to get all updates including fileCompletedCount and fileTotalCount
let progress = Progress()
progress.observe(\.localizedDescription) { p, c in
    print(p.fileTotalCount)
    print(p.fileCompletedCount)
}
progress.fileCompletedCount = 10
progress.fileTotalCount = 11

nil
Optional(10)
Optional(11)
Optional(10)


That's basically just what I said: "observe some property that is explicitly observable".

@matt fractionCompleted does not trigger the change. Is the localizedDescription that will get the update if something has changed in the userinfo.
